# Toggle between select/deselect UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button which I want to change background color and text when tapped(select) and bring it back to its original state when tapped again (deselect). I am able to select it but I am not being able to deselect it. I have researched on SO and I am getting errors in this code in the if-else part

```
   @IBAction func btn1Pressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
        (sender as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        if sender.isSelected {
            sender.selected = false
        }
        else {
            sender.selected = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try change it to `(sender as! UIButton).selected = !(sender as! UIButton).selected`

Comment: It is not going back to its original state but there is a blue highligth

Comment: What is your default background color ad text? In your code you only change the button property to your selected state, not reverting back

Comment: default background color is blue and text is green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }

    if !button.isSelected {
        button.isSelected = true
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
    else {
        button.isSelected = false
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Both select/deselect works, the only thing is when I select the button there is a blue highlight across font

Comment: Change button's tintColor to clearColor in storyboard :D

Comment: That worked perfectly :) . One more question if you don't mind, I have ten of these buttons , so do I need to write action method for all these ten buttons

Comment: Try search about outlet group, then you can make an array of your buttons, then in viewDidLoad make a loop and add the same action for them, very fast

Answer (score 0):

Change background color of selected button from `storyboard` like below in `state config` choose `selected` and then change background color and also coustomize default for normal button.

[image]

and use below in action

```
(sender as! UIButton).selected = !(sender as! UIButton).selected
```

Comment: I am getting error message "Cannot assign to property:'sender' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: check my updated answer, from storyboard customize selected and default button configuration and in his action just toggle button state.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @IBAction func btn1Pressed(sender: UIButton) {


    if sender.selected {
        sender.selected = false
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
         sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


    }
    else {
        sender.selected = true
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Selected)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before and i got these errors "Type "Bool" is broken" and "Cannot assign to property:'sender' is a 'let' constant"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like UISwitch is what you're looking for. Give it a try instead of wasting time implementing something that's already there for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code first you need to crate action and propert of the button like

```
@IBOutlet var btn_ButtonPressed: UIButton!
```

then Action.

```
    @IBAction func click_ButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
  if !sender.isSelected() {
    sender.selected = true
    btn_ButtonPressed.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, forState: .normal)
    btn_ButtonPressed.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
else {
    sender.selected = false
    btn_ButtonPressed.setTitleColor(UIColor.yellow, forState: .normal)
    btn_ButtonPressed.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried exactly the same and i got these errors "Type "Bool" is broken" and "Cannot assign to property:'sender' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: @Coder221 you take its outlet to change isSelected property.

Answer (score 0):

this one worked fine for me!
//
@IBAction func buttonColorChanger(sender : UIButton ) {

```
if button.isSelected == false
{

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    print("selected")

    button.setTitle("selected", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
     button.isSelected = true
}else{

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    print("unselected")
    button.isSelected = false

}
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach would be:

```
@objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()

    if selected {
        // Setup appearance for selected state.
    } else {
        // Setup appearance for deselected state.
    }
}
```